# Regular Expression to Catch multi-line quote

Tags: regex, r, text-processing

```
...,"My quote goes on
to multiple lines
like this",...
```

How would I catch this in a regular expression? I want to do this in a substitution to end up with

```
....,"My quote goes on to multiple lines like this",...
```

I tried

```
"(?<!\")\r\n(?!\")"
```

This was in an attempt to find a newline that does NOT end with a quote, and the next line does not start with a quote either.

The following substitution was done in R using that regular expression with no luck...

```
newDF = gsub( "(?<!\")\r\n(?!\")", " ", newDF, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: What is the language/tool?

Comment: Will edit that in. I am using R.  gsub is doing the sub.

Answer (score 0):

You can match a quoted substring and then use [**gsubfn**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/) to replace linebreaks inside the quoted substrings only:

```
library(gsubfn)
s = "...,\"My quote goes on\r\nto multiple lines\r\nlike this\",..."
gsubfn("\"[^\"]+\"", function(x) gsub("(?:\r?\n)+", " ", x), s)
[1] "...,\"My quote goes on to multiple lines like this\",..."
```

The `"[^"]+"` pattern matches all quoted substrings, and then `(?:\r?\n)+` matches 1 or more sequences of an optional CR (`\r?`) followed with 1 LF (that are replaced with a space).

Alternatively, you can achieve a similar result with a PCRE regex like

```
gsub("(?:\r?\n)+(?!(?:[^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*$)", " ", s, perl=T)
[1] "...,\"My quote goes on to multiple lines like this\",..."
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJ4xJ3/1). The `(?!(?:[^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*$)` lookahead makes sure there are no even quotes up to the string end.

Answer (score 0):

```
> x <- "My quote goes on
+ to multiple lines
+ like this"

> gsub("\\n", " ", x)
[1] "My quote goes on to multiple lines like this"
```

Don't forget to double the backslashes.